# Raspbian Stretch install imapclient to Python 3.5.3

Tags: python, raspbian-stretch

*Why I need it:* I've run into an issue where I first wrote a python script using imapclient to check my gmail using Python 2.7. Then continuing the path to full automation I made another script which uses subprocess.run which is not supported in Python 2.7. So the issues is I can't use python 2.7 with imapclient AND python 3.5 subprocess.run in the same python script. However, https://pypi.org/project/IMAPClient/ states the following:

> Python versions 2.7 and 3.4 through 3.7 are officially supported.

*What I need:* How do I install imapclient to python 3.5.3 in Raspbian Stretch? The following only installs it to Python 2.7:

```
sudo pip install imapclient
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 and 3 use their own (separate) libraries and you have to install it for both versions separately.

Replace `pip` with `pip3` to install for Python 3:

```
sudo pip3 install imapclient
```